Getting react-native-i18n:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error
I am trying to upgrade Android sdk version for our React Native app. After updating bunch of dependencies to fix various errors along the way, now I have landed on this error, and I am kind of stuck. I hope someone can help with that. After I run ./gradlew clean  and ./gradlew assembleDebug  I am getting this error for the react-native-i18n  package
> Task :react-native-i18n:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:3: error: package com.facebook.react does not exist
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
                         ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:4: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
                                ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:5: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
                                ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:6: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
                                ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:7: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
                                   ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
public class RNI18nPackage implements ReactPackage {
                                      ^
  symbol: class ReactPackage
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class RNI18nPackage
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
              ^
  symbol:   class NativeModule
  location: class RNI18nPackage
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                                              ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class RNI18nPackage
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
              ^
  symbol:   class ViewManager
  location: class RNI18nPackage
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:6: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
                                ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:7: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
                                ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:8: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
                                ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:9: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
                                ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:10: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
                                ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:11: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableArray;
                                ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
public class RNI18nModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
                                  ^
  symbol: class ReactContextBaseJavaModule
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
  public RNI18nModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                      ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class RNI18nModule
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
  private WritableArray getLocaleList() {
          ^
  symbol:   class WritableArray
  location: class RNI18nModule
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
  public void getLanguages(Promise promise) {
                           ^
  symbol:   class Promise
  location: class RNI18nModule
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactMethod
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactMethod
  location: class RNI18nModule
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:15: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(new RNI18nModule(reactContext));
                   ^
  symbol:   class NativeModule
  location: class RNI18nPackage
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nPackage.java:25: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:23: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    WritableArray array = Arguments.createArray();
    ^
  symbol:   class WritableArray
  location: class RNI18nModule
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    WritableArray array = Arguments.createArray();
                          ^
  symbol:   variable Arguments
  location: class RNI18nModule
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
      LocaleList locales = getReactApplicationContext()
                           ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class RNI18nModule
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
      array.pushString(this.toLanguageTag(getReactApplicationContext()
                                          ^
  symbol:   method getReactApplicationContext()
  location: class RNI18nModule
/Users/sefakose/repos/irecommend-mobile/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java:73: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
30 errors

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-i18n:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 21s

I upgraded java version from 11 to 17 and also react native version to 0.65.3 Connected to that I updated gradle to this version
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip

and here is my android/build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.0"
        RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        // supportLibVersion = "33.0.0"
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
            }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            // All of Detox' artifacts are provided via the npm module
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/detox/Detox-android"
        }
    }
    //  configurations.all {
    //       resolutionStrategy {
    //         force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + "0.65.3"
    //       }
    // }
}

subprojects { subproject ->
        if(project['name'] == 'react-native-i18n'){
            project.configurations { compile { } }
        }
}

Here is android/app/build.gradle
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

// override which node gets called and with what additional arguments

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,
    nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"]
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    namespace 'test' // Update this with your actual package name
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 362
        versionName "2.1.9"
        testBuildType System.getProperty('testBuildType', 'debug')
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        manifestPlaceholders = [
            appAuthRedirectScheme: defaultConfig.applicationId, 
            auth0Domain: "test", 
            auth0Scheme: "test"
        ]
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            // Detox-specific additions to pro-guard
            proguardFile "${rootProject.projectDir}/../node_modules/detox/android/detox/proguard-rules-app.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.4.1")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    

    androidTestImplementation('com.wix:detox:+') { transitive = true }
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

task checkNodeVersion {
    doLast {
        def nodeVersion = 'node -v'.execute().text.trim()
        println "Node.js version: ${nodeVersion}"
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "irecommend",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "cc": "rimraf node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/*,",
    "ios": "npm run cc && react-native run-ios",
    "android": "npm run cc && react-native run-android",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "android-run-release": "react-native run-android --variant=release",
    "android-build-release": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/ && rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-* && rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/raw/* && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..",
    "debug": "open 'rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081'",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@crowdin/ota-client": "^1.1.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.4",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "https://github.com/flyingSAP/react-native-blur",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^2.4.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "big-integer": "^1.6.52",
    "hermes-engine": "0.10.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "qs": "^6.10.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-devtools": "^4.24.7",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.65",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-app-auth": "7.0.0",
    "react-native-check-version": "^1.0.18",
    "react-native-contacts": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.2.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.5.5",
    "react-native-eventemitter": "^0.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^5.6.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-localization": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "7.29.1",
    "react-native-option-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-sha256": "^1.4.10",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.22.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-oidc": "^4.0.0-beta1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "shell-quote": "1.7.3",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "detox": "^18.20.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-circus": "^27.0.6",
    "json-schema": ">=0.4.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./app/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "private": true
}

I added the dependency to the android/settings.gradle  as well.
rootProject.name = 'irecommend'
include ':react-native-svg'
project(':react-native-svg').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-svg/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-i18n'
project(':react-native-i18n').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-i18n/android')
include ':app'

I have updated packages.

It's going to be hard to find relevant resources for versions of React Native that are 3+ years old and a package (react-native-i18n) which hasn't been updated in 6 years. If you are updating your app, why aren't you actually updating the dependencies? You're gonna get stuck in a hell of mismatching versions/dependencies this way.

@nbokmans Yes thats a better approach of course. But for now a workaround would be ok for me because of the urgency. But I am stuck anyway :)
